# Get amount of pixels scrolled from a div's height + its distance from the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, distance, parallax

I'm looking for a way in jQuery or pure JS to get the amount of pixels scrolled, not from the top of the page, but from the bottom of a div.

In other words I need to turn the amount scrolled beyond a div's height + its pixel distance from the top of the page into a variable.

I want to append this parallax code below so instead of calculating from the top of the page, calculates from a target div's distance from the top + its height.

```
/* Parallax Once Threshold is Reached */

var triggerOne = $('#trigger-01').offset().top;     

$(window).scroll(function(e){

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= triggerOne) {

    function parallaxTriggerOne(){                                   
      var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
      $('#test').css('top',+(scrolled*0.2)+'px');
    }

    parallaxTriggerOne();

  } else {
    $('#test').css('top','initial');
  }  

});
```

I realize I didn't phrase this quite clear enough, I'm looking to only get the value of the amount of pixels scrolled since passing a div, so for example if I had a 200px tall div at the very top of the page and I scrolled 20 pixels beyond it, that variable I need would equal 20, not 220.

Comment: I wanted to note that switching "$(window).scrollTop();" in my function above to "$(window).scrollTop() - ($('#trigger-01').offset().top + 2);" works perfectly for my needs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a div's position by using `div.offsetTop`, 
adding `div.offsetHeight` into div's distance from top of page will give you bottom of div, then you can subtract from window's scroll to get your desired value.

Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('foo');
let div_bottom = div.offsetTop + div.offsetHeight;
var doc = document.documentElement;
var left = (window.pageXOffset || doc.scrollLeft) - (doc.clientLeft || 0);
var scroll_top, scroll_after_div;

setInterval(function(){
  scroll_top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);
  scroll_after_div = scroll_top - div_bottom;
  console.log(scroll_after_div);
}, 1000);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="position:relative; top: 100px; height: 30px; width: 100%; background-color: #000;"></div>

<div id="bar" style="position:relative; top: 700px; height: 30px; width: 100%; background-color: #000;"></div>
```

In this snippet `setInterval` method is printing the scroll value each second, you can scroll and see the change in value.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To work out the distance from the top of the page to the bottom of an element, you can add an elements `outerHeight()` with its `offset().top`.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dw2jwLpw/

```
console.log(
    $('.target').outerHeight() + $('.target').offset().top
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure JS you can get the bottom of the div directly with `document.getElementById("my-element").getBoundingClientRect().bottom`.

In jQuery you can use `$('#my-element').offset().top + $('#my-element').height()`